# VBA Excel, loop through a column and hide column if cells contain substrings

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop over a column I specify and if one of the cells in that column contain a substring, if hide the row there the cell is located.

This:

```
A       B
aaaccc  456
adzass  46
ddamdd  784
sdadaz  789
```

would become this:

```
A       B
aaaccc  456
ddamdd  784
```

This is my code so far:

```
 Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, "B") Like "*KB*" Or Cells(i, "B") Like "*KZ*" Then
        '' MsgBox Cells(i, "B").Value
            Cells(i, "B").Row.Hidden
        End If
    Next i
```

I assumed I could get the row of the cells by doing `Cells(i, "B").Row` but it doesn't seem to return it.

Comment: and the normal filter won't work because...?

Comment: Can a normal filter hide a row based on a substring?

Comment: yes it can.  You would use the text filters option and does not contain.

Comment: or in code: `Range("A2:B" & N).autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*KB*"`

Comment: Select one cell in your data area, Go to Insert menu and Insert Table, choose that you have headers and then it will give you a nice structured dataset with auto filters, you can do a lot more advanced filters, just play with it and you will discover maybe more than what you want

Comment: Moreover, if you want to create the code for autofiltering with one or more criteria then records a macro, manually use the autofilter of the table and then you can see how Excel is doing it, you can simply save that code and use it, remember if you do filtration using a code, most likely you will need to write more code, such as making sure that the autofilter is active, show all records etc

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to apply multiple (20+) "do not contain" filter on the same column without code? something like does not contain "kb1" OR "zu1" etc.

Comment: You'd need to use the `Advanced Filter`.  I think the `Auto Filter` has a limit of three conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim N As Long, i As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To N
    If Cells(i, "A") Like "*z*" Then 'changed criteria
        'MsgBox Cells(i, "A").Value
        Rows(i).Hidden = True 'Use Rows(rowindex) to get the row object
    End If
Next i
```

The above code should do the trick.

A few things:

- Your if statement doesn't match any of the row you want to hide, so I changed it a bit.
- Cells(i, "B").Row gives you the row index, not the row object itself
- .Hidden is a property, you need to set it to true or false. Hence: Rows(i).Hidden = True